# How can i get value from textbox?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I've started C++ 1 week ago and learnt a lot of useful things. Now i'm coding a hack for an online game. i did it like that;

```
DWORD ENEMY = 0x01516370; //Base address
DWORD ENEMY_OFFSET = 0x4;

void Map1Function(bool fEnable)
{
 if(fEnable)
 {
WritePointer(ENEMY, ENEMY_OFFSET, textbox1->Text);
}
else
 { 
WritePointer(ENEMY, ENEMY_OFFSET, textbox1->Text);
 }
}
```

How can i get value from textbox ? Thanks.

My function :

```
#include <Windows.h>
bool WritePointer(unsigned long ulBase, int iOffset, int iValue)
{
  __try { *(int*)(*(unsigned long*)ulBase + iOffset) = iValue; return true; }
  __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) { return false; }
}
```

But it gives that error when i do it like that ^ :

```
c:\users\*\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tutorial\tutorial\Hacks.h(63): error         C2065: 'textbox1' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\*\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tutorial\tutorial\Hacks.h(63): error  C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\*\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tutorial\tutorial\Hacks.h(67): error C2065: 'textbox1' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\*\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tutorial\tutorial\Hacks.h(67): error  C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
```

Full src :

```
#pragma once

namespace Tutorial {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
         // </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^  groupBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel^  linkLabel1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;



protected: 

protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
        this->groupBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->linkLabel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabel());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->checkBox8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->checkBox7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->checkBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->checkBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->checkBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->checkBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->radioButton3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
        this->radioButton2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
        this->radioButton1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
        this->checkBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->checkBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->groupBox1->SuspendLayout();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this->groupBox1->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"groupBox1.BackgroundImage")));
        this->groupBox1->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Zoom;
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->linkLabel1);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox8);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox7);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox6);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox5);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox4);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox3);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->radioButton3);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->radioButton2);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->radioButton1);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox2);
        this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->checkBox1);
        this->groupBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->groupBox1->Name = L"groupBox1";
        this->groupBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(856, 799);
        this->groupBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->groupBox1->TabStop = false;
        this->groupBox1->Text = L"Functions";
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(115, 273);
        this->textBox1->Multiline = true;
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(54, 18);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 13;
        // 
        // linkLabel1
        // 
        this->linkLabel1->AutoSize = true;
        this->linkLabel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(9, 309);
        this->linkLabel1->Name = L"linkLabel1";
        this->linkLabel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(114, 15);
        this->linkLabel1->TabIndex = 12;
        this->linkLabel1->TabStop = true;
        this->linkLabel1->Text = L"www.elitepvpers.com";
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(9, 294);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 15);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 11;
        this->label1->Text = L"Credits : SilverEmerald";
        // 
        // checkBox8
        // 
        this->checkBox8->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 272);
        this->checkBox8->Name = L"checkBox8";
        this->checkBox8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(103, 19);
        this->checkBox8->TabIndex = 10;
        this->checkBox8->Text = L"Room Password";
        this->checkBox8->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox8->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox8_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox7
        // 
        this->checkBox7->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 247);
        this->checkBox7->Name = L"checkBox7";
        this->checkBox7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(83, 19);
        this->checkBox7->TabIndex = 9;
        this->checkBox7->Text = L"No Gravity";
        this->checkBox7->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox7->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox7_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox6
        // 
        this->checkBox6->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 222);
        this->checkBox6->Name = L"checkBox6";
        this->checkBox6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(76, 19);
        this->checkBox6->TabIndex = 1;
        this->checkBox6->Text = L"Cam Hack";
        this->checkBox6->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox6->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox6_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox5
        // 
        this->checkBox5->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 197);
        this->checkBox5->Name = L"checkBox5";
        this->checkBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(85, 19);
        this->checkBox5->TabIndex = 8;
        this->checkBox5->Text = L"Infinite SP";
        this->checkBox5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox5->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox5_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox4
        // 
        this->checkBox4->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 172);
        this->checkBox4->Name = L"checkBox4";
        this->checkBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(124, 19);
        this->checkBox4->TabIndex = 7;
        this->checkBox4->Text = L"HP Refill / Suicide";
        this->checkBox4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox4->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox4_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox3
        // 
        this->checkBox3->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 147);
        this->checkBox3->Name = L"checkBox3";
        this->checkBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(163, 19);
        this->checkBox3->TabIndex = 6;
        this->checkBox3->Text = L"[Conquest] Frozen Enemies";
        this->checkBox3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox3->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox3_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // radioButton3
        // 
        this->radioButton3->AutoSize = true;
        this->radioButton3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 122);
        this->radioButton3->Name = L"radioButton3";
        this->radioButton3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(81, 19);
        this->radioButton3->TabIndex = 5;
        this->radioButton3->TabStop = true;
        this->radioButton3->Text = L"Deactivate";
        this->radioButton3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->radioButton3->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::radioButton3_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // radioButton2
        // 
        this->radioButton2->AutoSize = true;
        this->radioButton2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 97);
        this->radioButton2->Name = L"radioButton2";
        this->radioButton2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(72, 19);
        this->radioButton2->TabIndex = 4;
        this->radioButton2->TabStop = true;
        this->radioButton2->Text = L"HitRange";
        this->radioButton2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->radioButton2->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::radioButton2_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // radioButton1
        // 
        this->radioButton1->AutoSize = true;
        this->radioButton1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 72);
        this->radioButton1->Name = L"radioButton1";
        this->radioButton1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(79, 19);
        this->radioButton1->TabIndex = 3;
        this->radioButton1->TabStop = true;
        this->radioButton1->Text = L"WallShoot";
        this->radioButton1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->radioButton1->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::radioButton1_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox2
        // 
        this->checkBox2->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 47);
        this->checkBox2->Name = L"checkBox2";
        this->checkBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(106, 19);
        this->checkBox2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->checkBox2->Text = L"Design Changer";
        this->checkBox2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox2->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox2_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this->checkBox1->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 22);
        this->checkBox1->Name = L"checkBox1";
        this->checkBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(69, 19);
        this->checkBox1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->checkBox1->Text = L"No Blast";
        this->checkBox1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->checkBox1->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::checkBox1_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(7, 15);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(705, 344);
        this->Controls->Add(this->groupBox1);
        this->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Comic Sans MS", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(162)));
        this->MaximizeBox = false;
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"S4League EU In-Game Hack 23.03.14";
        this->groupBox1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->groupBox1->PerformLayout();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox8_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox5_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox6_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox7_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);      
};
}
```

Comment: `textbox1->Text`, are you not getting expected value?

Comment: Please share with us what library are you using.

Comment: I added my function and errors in thread.

Comment: So `textbox1` does not exist. Which textbox are you using?

Comment: Huh. It's in my form.. http://i59.tinypic.com/24uys9d.png

Comment: Im I right you are you using .NET with C++/CLI? Can you move `Map1Function` from Hacks.h to the same file (class) as your form?

Comment: Didn't work, sorry. I also tried it with RichTextbox. it didn't work either.

Comment: I'm stuck here. i've tried everything, i also posted my full src now. Any more helps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *textBox1*, not *textbox1*; variables are case sensitive.

Also, this won't work, you need to convert the *string* from the *Text* property to an int value. You will need this:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    int value = Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);
    WritePointer(ENEMY, ENEMY_OFFSET, value);
}
```

Notice how the textBox1 is used within the Form1 class. It is necessary because the textBox1 is private to the class.

Comment: Check again for the edit I made for Convert instead of atoi. Then, post the error, because it must have changed! At least, the textBox1 should have been recognized.

Comment: Here is the errors : http://i59.tinypic.com/11in8fm.png There are some  warnings too but i am not sure.

Comment: Ok, you have a conceptual flaw in using the textBox1 outside the class it is declared. The designer declared it private for a reason, you need to access it from within the class (check the last edit), or use accessors to make the values available outside. For your small project, move the code from Hacks.h to Form1.h.

Comment: Thanks. i'll try this and post the result in here.